# How can i trigger a one signal notification from my ionic app using the one signal rest api. i had gone through the doc but am not getting it

Tags: typescript, rest, ionic-framework, onesignal

How can i trigger a one signal notification from my ionic app using the one signal. i had gone through the doc but am not getting it.I had also set up the service and its working fine but i can only push a manual notification from the one signal website. Am seeking to dynamically trigger the notification from my app using the rest api provided by one signal. this is the link to the doc https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for our `postNotification` [method](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk#section--postnotification-)

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the notification with a REST URL to mobile with the help of unique PlayerID/SubscriptionID,

```
POST https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications
Authorization: Basic YOUR_API_KEY
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "app_id": "YOUR_APP_ID",
  "include_player_ids": ["PLAYER_ID"],
  "contents": {"en": "Notification Content"},
  "headings": {"en": "Notification Title"}
}
```

For Reference you can use the below curl,

```
curl --location 'https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Basic: **YOUR API KEY**' \
--data '{
  "app_id": "**YOUR APP ID**",
  "include_player_ids": ["PLAYERID/SUBSCRIPTIONID"],
  "contents": {"en": "Title"},
  "headings": {"en": "Description"}
}'
```